# Swing design JTable auto refresh?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a question about my application's design.

I have 2 `JTable`s (with my own `TableModel`) and I want to create a third table, which is built based on the selection in the other two tables. So when I start my application nothing is selected and this third table is supposed to be empty.

How do I find out what is selected in the two tables and how do I refresh the third one?

Comment: See ["How to use tables"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

> *How do I find out what is selected in the two tables and how do I refresh the third one?*

Please note you have two different yet related problems here.

First one is about selection in tables (see [User Selections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) section of [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial). Basically you need to attach a [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) to the table's [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) in order to listen for selection changes. Something like this:

```
JTable table1 = new JTable();
table1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // Implementation here
    }
});
```

See [JTable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html):

- [public ListSelectionModel getSelectionModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel--)
- [public int[] getSelectedRows()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows--)
- [public int getSelectedRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRowCount--)
- [public int convertRowIndexToModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-)

The second problem is about refreshing/updating your third table. In order to accomplish this you need to work with the ***model*** of this third table by adding/removing/updating rows. Then this model will notify the ***view*** that something has changed and your table will be automatically updated.